# Using \hat on greek letters in equation environment results in blank space

Tags: environments, greek

Using `\hat` on Greek letters in the equation environment results in a blank space.

The code I'm using is:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\rho}_{non lin} = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{ \hat{P}\cdot\hat{E} } = \frac{1}{2} \hat{P}_i\hat{E}_i
\approx \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_0 \chi_{ijk}^{(2)} \hat{E}_{i} \hat{E}_{j} \hat{E}_{k}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Overleaf computes everything else correctly but doesn't show the Greek letter with the hat.
EDIT: added an image to show the problem

[image: image showing the problem]

If I remove the `\hat` command, the code works fine but it's not what I want. Outside the equation environment, using `$\hat{\rho}$` works without problems.

Comment: Can you please make a complete minimal example? Here I get nice hats also on greek letters.

Comment: Unrelated: `_{\text{non lin}}` is a very bad idea, `\text` is not for writing some text upright. Use `\textup` or `\textnormal` instead. Why? Try `\itshape $X_{\text{max}}`, `\text{max}` comes out in italic. Not what we want for a named index.

Comment: The equation number in the picture appears misplaced, which may denote some other problem. Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @egreg not getting any errors from Overleaf

Comment: @a_dragon08 Please, report the *exact* code you're using, without attempting to format it.

Comment: @egreg I edited the question to show the complete code,
sorry but I'am also new to StackExchange

Comment: Please make a complete small example. If I add `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}`  It does not show a missing rho.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle YES! it was just that! 
Sorry for the stupid mistake, may I ask why Latex behaves in this way?
egreg thanks to you too for answering

Comment: Do not ignore error mssages! Overleaf will haave a red circle with an error count and   a mark at the line number of your source. Also post your _real code_ here, You have not posted any code with a blank line that would show the error.  A blank line is end-of-paragraph and you can not end a paragraph in the middle of math.

Answer (score 4):

From the output I would assume you have a blank line after `\begin{equation}`

This generates.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.9 
    
?
```

In Overleaf it will make a red error mark and you can check the log for the full error.

Do not ignore error messages! Overleaf will have a red circle with an error count and   a mark at the line number of your source. Also post your *real code* here, You have not posted any code with a blank line that would show the error.  A blank line is end-of-paragraph and you can not end a paragraph in the middle of math.